# Sitecore development on local computer

Tags: sitecore

Currently I have a Primary 1 server Sitecore license which is hosted on a live server. my question is can I use this license to setup a copy of the site on my local machine or would this require an upgraded Sitecore license?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend asking your Sitecore sales rep for an official answer to this question. Unofficially, though, I think you're in the clear to use your license for a local development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam, just trying to get as much background information as I can. Can you also tell me how I set up multiple sites using sitecore?

Comment: See this for multiple sites configuration: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites.aspx